# Separate scrolling columns in a webpage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a website similar to `www.the5th.co` where they have two independent columns. Both columns are scrollable but independently. How should I approach in developing a design like this? what languages would I need? I am trying to achieve this design in WordPress if that's possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should get basic information about programming languages for developing webpages and after this ask the question again but more accurate. For inspecting websites to check their design, there are several debugging and monitoring tools like [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox. A simple way to do this seperate scrolling is to use simple HTML and CSS. However there are various techniques to implement this. One of them is shown here:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#col_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#col1 {
  float: left;
}
#col2 {
  overflow: hidden;

}
#col1, #col2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; 
}
.col-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
}
.col-content > div {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
.col-content p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="col_container">
    <div id="col1">
      <div class="col-content">
        <div>
          <p>Hallo World!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <div class="col-content">
        <div>
          <p>Hallo World!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```